# rebuild the xDB index in Azure Search didn't finished

Tags: xdb, azure, azure-search

I followed [this article](https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-search-indexer/rebuild-index/rebuild-azure-index.html) to rebuild the xDB index in Azure Search.

About 2 hours after the rebuild index process started, i noticed that the rebuild process seemed to stopped (document of xdb-secondary didn't continue to rise).

But when i tried to check if rebuild was complete with the query : $filter=id eq 'xdb-rebuild-status', i didn't get a RebuildState of 6 indicates that rebuild has completed.

I also checked log files of xc-search AppService but could not see any error.

I want to know if i can check log of Azure Search to see errors (With Solr Search, we can see it's log) ?

If yes where can i check ?

Comment: Try checking Azure AppInsights for any messages related to IndexWorker web job. If AppInsights had not been enabled, please configure that and re-run index rebuild.